# Change of keyboard layout has no effect in VM

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, keyboard-layout

I am running a Kali Linux VM with VirtualBox on my MacBook. Because my laptop is rather old I decided to deactivate the GUI with the help of [this](https://gist.github.com/xErik/8cce03429ffe58809662) guide. I have a German keyboard, so I tried to change the layout to match it using:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and

```
service keyboard-setup restart
```

Afterwards it shows success and even the config file in `/etc/default/keyboard` shows the correct (German) layout, but typing shows that it still uses the us-layout (e.g. z and y are reversed). I don't know if it may have something to do with VirtualBox.

Comment: Update: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` sets the right layout, but only until I reboot; so still looking for a permanent solution

Comment: until you find a real solution you could write a systemd unit that runs this automatically on boot .

Answer (score 0):

To change globally keyboard settings,
refer to the manual page for [keyboard(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/keyboard.5.html). 
If you want to change the system language,
you need to modify `/etc/default/keyboard` with root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

You should see the following:
[image: screenshot of /etc/default/keyboard being edited]

Language tags can be found [at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs?view=windows-11).

For the keyboard model (XKBMODEL=""),
open `/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.config` –
the list has the structure [LANGUAGE_TAG]*model*[KEYBOARD_NAME]. 
The easiest way is to search by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Here is one command for the entire process. 
In my example, [KEYBOARD_NAME] is "asus_laptop"
and the language is German, so [LANGUAGE_TAG] is "de". 
XKBVARIANT="" and XKBOPTIONS="" remain unchanged.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "XKBMODEL=\"asus_laptop\"\nXKBLAYOUT=\"de\"\nXKBVARIANT=\"\"\nXKBOPTIONS=\"\"" > /etc/default/keyboard &&
     sed -i "/de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/s/^# //" /etc/locale.gen  &&
     locale-gen  &&
     update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8  &&
     echo "LANG=de_DE.UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.conf  &&
     echo "export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc'
```

Additionally, `update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`
updates the system locale settings
and the last add the appropriate lines
in `/etc/locale.conf` and `~/.bashrc` files.